# Need help identifying this chip on a old board

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Hi Can any body assist in identifying this chip (I think its Ram) probably an easy

[image]

Comment: is IDT the manufacturer?

Comment: I thought the "I"" might be an integral sign, but only guessing??

Comment: The PCB was made around 1990

Comment: Yes, IDT is the manufacturer. Very good parts, I designed IDT into many circuits in the late '80s and early '90s. Their FCT logic gates were very fast, altho static sensitive. Had to use ESD mats and be strapped to the mat when handling bare components.

Answer (score 4):

From what I could find, the manufacturer is Integrated Device Technology (hence the integral sign, it's part of their logo).

The chip is most likely the [7164 series asynchronous static RAM](https://www.idt.com/products/memory-logic/srams/asynchronous-srams/7164-50v-8k-x-8-asynchronous-static-ram).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is it still possible to purchase these chips or an equivalent?

Comment: @Fish5001 Not sure what country you are in, but [Digikey](https://www.digikey.nl/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/memory/774?FV=fffc0320&k=7164&pkeyword=7164&cur=EUR&lang=en) seems to have them in stock.